Python notebook causing ArcGIS Pro to crash
On my laptop are student licenses to ArcGIS Pro 3.2, ENVI 6.0 and Agisoft Metashape 2.0.3. I'm in an intro to GIS programming class and when I try to open a Python notebook in ArcGIS Pro (from the catalog pane) it crashes. I used to get an error, yet now it just crashes. I get "initializing Kernel" and then "please wait while gathering information about error ... ." My desktop is older and slower, yet it does not have ENVI and Metashape and the Python notebook opens just fine. I did some reading on the environment manager. Under Package Manager, I am only offered the default of acrgispro-py3.
I uninstalled ENVI and the problem remains, w/ same symptoms.

fyi Microsoft .NET Desktop Runtime (via Windows updates can cause issues) https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/arcgis-pro-crashing-repeatedly/td-p/1357043

As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks and other statements of appreciation within your posts.

Troubleshooting this error is difficult. Sometimes closing all the maps \ layouts, removing the notebook and adding it, creating a new map, or creating a new project will clear the kernel. You could try copying the notebook using your desktop and then adding the new copy to the project.
In the package manager I recommend creating a clone of the default environment, because if the clone gets corrupted then you can delete it and start over.
You can use the conda commandline to run the notebook outside of ArcGIS. If you find the Python Command Prompt under ArcGIS folder on the start\windows popup, then you can run the commands. Change the directory (e.g. cd c:\temp) to get to the folder with the notebook. Then run jupyter-lab to open the notebook in a different kernel.
